# Laptop can remote desktop with desktop PC, but not vice versa. PC can't even ping laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, remote-desktop

I own a laptop running windows 10, and a desktop running windows 10. I'd like to remote connect from the desktop to the laptop. My laptop is connected to the 5G Wi-Fi and my desktop is wired via ethernet cable to the same router.

When I use Remote Desktop to connect between my laptop and desktop, it works fine. The laptop prompts me for my desktops password, then grants me access. When I try the other way, I get nothing (keep in mind I'm using IPv4 addresses to connect).

The command prompt from my desktop wont even ping the laptop. So far I have made sure all the computers have the "Allow remote assistance" checked (however the laptops don't have the remote desktop option for some reason), and I made sure all the processes were running for RDP. How can I remote desktop from my desktop to my laptop?

*Just another piece of information: my laptop wont connect to another laptop on the network either, or the other way back.*

Answer (score 0):

try disable firewall on laptop from control Panel> Windows Firewall > Turn Windows Firewall on or Off > Off

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Both the laptop and the desktop are running windows 10 pro. I could connect remote desktop to my desktop from my laptop but not the other way around. I finally found that there were settings inside my Norton security suite I had to change. I had to open the Norton Security suite command center, then select SECURITY>ADVANCED> and turned the SMART FIREWALL, and INTRUSION PREVENTION to OFF. After that it worked fine. Note: You can set the limits for how long you want the settings to remain off, or you can select permanently. Funny but those settings on my desktop were set to on, and my laptop had no problem connecting. Probably because the desktop is connected thru an Ethernet connection, and the laptop is using Wi-Fi. So if you don't have Norton, search inside of what ever software is controlling your firewall. Hope this helps!